# SQL join (include/exclude) not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join

In my PHP/Mysql application, I have 3 tables to store product/function information:

```
product
id      brand      ref      mod
2675    Brand 1    123456   Model X
3644    Brand 2    78910    Model Y
3984    Brand 3    35532    Model Z

function
id   name          active    sort_order
0    NONE          1         0
1    Function 1    1         0
2    Function 2    1         0
3    Function 3    1         0

product2function
id   product_id   function_id
2    2675         1
3    3644         1
4    3644         2
5    3984         1
```

Table product2function is used to make the link between the products and the function(s) available on them.

One product can have one or multiple functions.

The SQL query using JOIN to get the available function(s) for a given product id is not a problem, it works fine.

Now I need to setup a SQL query which should return more accurate results:

In example, I need to retrieve all product(s) having ONLY function 1 (id=1). Not function 1 and maybe one or many other, ONLY function 1.

In my case, that means product 3644 should not be returned as it has function id=1 and also function id=2.

I'm trying to get the expected result using IN syntax but with no success.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.id, a.brand
FROM    product a
        INNER JOIN product2function b
            On a.ID = b.product_id
WHERE   b.function_id = 1 AND
        EXISTS  -- this part checks the number of functions of the product
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    product2function c
            WHERE   c.product_id = b.product_id
            GROUP   BY  c.product_id
            HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT function_id) = 1
        )
GROUP   BY  a.id, a.brand
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9be9c/1)

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═════════╗
║  ID  ║  BRAND  ║
╠══════╬═════════╣
║ 2675 ║ Brand 1 ║
║ 3984 ║ Brand 3 ║
╚══════╩═════════╝
```

Part of the questions states: *".. I need to retrieve all product(s) **having ONLY function 1** (id=1). **Not function 1 and maybe one or many other, ONLY function 1**."*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM product pr
WHERE EXISTS (
  -- all the products that have a Function=1
  SELECT *
  FROM product2function ex
  WHERE ex.product_id = pr.id
  AND ex.function_id = 1
  )
AND NOT EXISTS (
  -- ... but don't have an other function than 1
  SELECT *
  FROM product2function nx
  WHERE nx.product_id = pr.id
  AND nx.function_id <> 1
  )
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks wildpasser, your code is exactely what I needed. As I can specify multiple function to include and to exclude, I change the where clause using ex.function_id IN (1,2,...).

Comment: Dear wildpasser, I'm afraid I need to reopen this question because, the solution you gave yesterday, is working as long as I need to check ONLY one function.

In the data described above, if I only need to check if function=1, it works. 

As my products can have multiple function, I need to be able to build a SQL query returning ie only product having function=1 AND function=2.

Product having only function=1 or function=2 should NOT be returned.

I tried to add AND to the where clause, unfortunately with no success.

Hope you can help me.